# OPENGL_INVALID_OPERATION when calling glDrawElements

Tags: c++, opengl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl3ext.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

SDL_Window * window = NULL;
SDL_GLContext context = NULL;

const GLfloat vertices[3][4] = {
    0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  // Top Right
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // Bottom Right
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // Bottom Left
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f   // Top Left
};

const GLuint indices[3][2]= {  // Note that we start from 0!
    0, 1, 3,   // First Triangle
    1, 2, 3    // Second Triangle
};

const GLchar* vertexShaderSource = {"#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;"
"void main(void)\n"
"{\n"
"gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);\n"
"}\n\0"};

//fragment
const GLchar* fragmentShaderSource = {"#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 color;\n"
"void main(void)\n"
"{\n"
"color = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0);\n"
"}\n\0"};

bool init ();

bool init(){
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)<0){
        std::cout << "Can't make SDL" << std::endl;
    }

    //what version we are using
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute (SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    //SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1);

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Rectangle", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 512, 512, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if (!window){
        std::cout << "No window created" << std::endl;
        window = NULL;
        return false;
    }

    context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    //double buffering - 24bit z buffer (might need changing for different systems)
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

    //Makes buffer swap sync with VBLANK
    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);

    glViewport(0, 0, 512, 512);

    return true;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    if (!init()) std::cout << "Failed to start up!" << std::endl;

    //compiling the shaders
    GLuint shaderProgram, fragmentShader, vertexShader;

    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    //error checking
    GLchar info [512];
    GLint success;
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success){
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, info);
        std::cout << "Did not compile fragment shader\n"<< info;
    }

    std::cout<< "vertex shader made" << std::endl;

    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    //error checking
    GLchar infoLog [512];
    GLint success2;
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success2);
    if(!success){
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "Did not compile vertex shader\n" << info;
    }

    std::cout << "fragment shader made" << std::endl;

    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    //error checking
    GLchar info3 [512];
    GLint success3;
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success3);
    if(!success){
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, info3);
        std::cout << "Did not link shaders\n" << info;
    }

    std::cout << "shaders linked" << std::endl;

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    //sets all the VAOs, VBOs, etcs
    GLuint VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);

    GLuint VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    GLuint EBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (GLvoid*)0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    bool loop = true;

    while (loop) {
        SDL_Event e;
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)){
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) loop = false;
            if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){
                switch(e.key.keysym.sym){
                    case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                        loop = false;
                        break;
                    case SDLK_q:
                        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
                        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
                        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
                        glBindVertexArray(0);
                        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
                        break;
                    case SDLK_y:
                        std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
                }
                std::cout << glGetError() << std::endl;
            }
        }

    }

}

//generates error 1282 for some reason
```

I used `glGetError` to see what the error was and it returned 1282, or `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. Whenever I try to draw, it causes a glitchy image (will upload pic later).

The problem is definitely not the shaders, because they compile just fine.
I think it's probably how I set up the VBOs and VAO:

```
  //sets all the VAOs, VBOs, etcs
GLuint VAO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);

GLuint VBO;
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

GLuint EBO;
glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (GLvoid*)0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

I copied all of those straight from this tutorial https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Hello-Triangle

and the source code for the tutorial can be found here https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?code=getting-started/hellotriangle2

I compared my code to the tutorial's several times, checking if I had all the right calls and parameters, but I couldn't find anything wrong. I'm pretty sure I set it all up correctly. Does anyone more experienced than me see what I've done wrong?

**Edit**: Ok, so I got the line 440 as where the error is thrown. I don't know if I'm reading it wrong, but my code doesn't have 440 lines in it. Does it mean line 4, character 40? I also moved `SetSwapInterval()` and `SDL_GL_Doublebuffer` functions to after the context was made.

**Edit 2**: Ok, so after some more digging, the line the error was thrown at was 439, (I had a load of commented out stuff which is why the number is so big), right after `glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0)`. The complaint is `INVALID_OPERATION`. It also said `INVALID_VALUE` at line 405 - the line after`glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);` when I started up the program, but didn't say it again.

**Edit 3**: After some more checking, it's definitely `glDrawElements()` that's causing this, not anything else.

Comment: Use [Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output) and/or pinpoint which line **exactly** generates the error.

Comment: Is it possible to use Debug Output on macs?

Comment: I don't know. If it is not, then don't use macs for development.

Comment: Which gl-command gives error?

Comment: Why are you trying to call `SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval()` before you have a current GL context?

Comment: Debug Output is not supported on macOS.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine It's not?  I had no idea.  Could you give me sources to that effect?  I'm genuinely curious.  I usually develop OpenGL stuff on Windows but wanted to port some code.

Comment: @Ripi2 It's `glDrawElements`